# Sorting multiple fields from an object in natural order

Tags: java, android, sorting, lambda

Currently I'm using a lamda sort to sort listID first, then Item Name second

```java
Comparator < Item > itemComparator = Comparator.comparing(Item::getListId)
                                               .thenComparing(Item::getItemName);
Collections.sort(itemList, itemComparator);
```

Which technically works, but ItemName is alphanumeric and sorts by ASCII instead of natural order
So instead of Item 0, Item 101, Item 28. I want Item 0, Item 28, Item 101. Is there a simple way to do this?

Edit: Item is taking info from a JSON File

```json
    [{"id": 684, "listId": 1, "name": "Item 684"},
    {"id": 276, "listId": 1, "name": "Item 276"},
    {"id": 808, "listId": 4, "name": "Item 808"},
    {"id": 680, "listId": 3, "name": "Item 680"},
    {"id": 534, "listId": 4, "name": "Item 534"},
    {"id": 906, "listId": 2, "name": "Item 906"},
    {"id": 735, "listId": 1, "name": "Item 735"},
```

Comment: Is it literally and always `"Item [NUMBER]"`? Can we see `Item`?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, but I put in extra data in the original question. Dunno if that's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"... So instead of Item 0, Item 101, Item 28. I want Item 0, Item 28, Item 101. Is there a simple way to do this? ..."*

You could parse the numeric value within *name*, from the closure.

```java
Comparator<Item> comparator
    = Comparator.comparing(Item::getListId)
                .thenComparing(value -> {
                    int indexOf = value.name.indexOf(' ');
                    return Integer.parseInt(value.name.substring(indexOf + 1));
                });
list.sort(comparator);
```

Output

```
[{id=276, listId=1, name='Item 276'},
 {id=684, listId=1, name='Item 684'},
 {id=735, listId=1, name='Item 735'},
 {id=906, listId=2, name='Item 906'},
 {id=680, listId=3, name='Item 680'},
 {id=534, listId=4, name='Item 534'},
 {id=808, listId=4, name='Item 808'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your added JSON, it appears that name is just the text "Item" and then the id. Which is numeric. Compare on that.

```
Comparator<Item> itemComparator = Comparator.comparing(Item::getListId)
        .thenComparing(Item::getId);
Collections.sort(itemList, itemComparator);
```

Comment: I thought about that, but this is part of a programming challenge and it explicitly states sorting by itemName. Specifically it says 

"Display all the items grouped by "listId"
Sort the results first by "listId" then by "name" when displaying.
Filter out any items where "name" is blank or null."

Comment: @Tiana Then you should probably use the lexical sort you already have. Otherwise you're going to have to parse the id back out and you have to make even more assumptions to do that correctly.